# Big O Runtime proof

Tags: calculus

How can be proven, that

$$ 
2^\sqrt{\log_2 n} \in O(n^\frac{1}{3})
$$

So the beginning should be something like this:

$$ 
2^\sqrt{\log_2 n} \le cn^\frac{1}{3}
$$

log on both sides:

$$ 
\sqrt{\log_2 n} * \log2 \le \frac{1}{3} log(cn)
$$

multiply with 3:

$$
3 * \sqrt\log_2 n* log 2 \le log c + logn
$$

At this point it could be proven with $n_0 = 10$ and $c = 10$ but I don't know if my alterations are correct. Can you please give me some hints to solve this problem?

Comment: By the way, there is a mistake in the 'divide by $\frac{1}{3}$' part. If $\sqrt{\log_2 n}\log 2\le \frac{1}{3}\log(cn)$, then $\color{red}{3}\sqrt{\log_2 n}\log 2\le \log(cn)$. (That is, the left-hand side should be multiplied by $3$, rather than divided by it.)

Comment: I corrected the mistake. Thank you!